# No response data by authentification

Tags: cakephp, authentication, bancha

using : cakePHP, Bancha, ExtJS

I try to create a login with ExtJS --> Bancha --> cakePHP.
ExtJS layout has been developed and I can call the cakePHP function `login` by Bancha. But if i call the the function, I get no result from the `$this->Auth->user()` function. I need the result (with username and role ) because serveral roles are allow to see serveral pages.

```
public function login($username = null, $password = null) {

        $logged = $this->Auth->login(); // result is boolean(true) all the time
        $userObj = $this->Auth->user(); // only the user name

        switch ($userObj['role']) { ... //  Illegal string offset 'role'
```

does anyone has a hint?

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've call the static function AuthContrller::users(). now it works.